# how can I rename/create apk with spacial charecters in the app name?

Tags: android, apk, penetration-testing

For my penetration test I need to rename/create APK so it would have “&" in the filename,
I did some try’s but noting yet.

I have tried to create new APK with "&" in eclipse but I can't create APK with such a name.
how can I compile APK with such a name?

Comment: I think you may try to set the app_name in strings.xml so that it includes an `&amp;` character

Answer (score 0):

You can create your .apk and rename it as you want: `myApp&Game.apk`. For example i have a project that generate an  .apk file called `Appsys.apk` then i rename it to `AntNews.apk`

but if you want to change the name of your app just add the html code into your `strings.xml`

```
  <string name="app_name">myApp&amp;Game</string>
```

Comment: not working, you can not create an apk because the xml have errors when the & is in it